# Is it possible to git diff equivalent with go-git

Tags: git, go, go-git

I'm pulling a repo every 10 seconds and need to check what files have changed after each pull.

Is it possible to do this with go-git?

Comment: Probably. Have you tried? Please explain how far you have gotten and what problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [(*object.Commit).Patch](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object#Commit.Patch) method to diff two arbitrary commits. This provides information about which files where changed and what the differences were.