# go-git diff between branches

Tags: go, go-git

It's possible with go-git to get the differences between two branches, or, for instance, current branch and master?

With GIT you can get diff between current branch and master:

```
$ git diff master
```

And between two branches:

```
$ git diff master feature/branch
```

I've find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731120/is-it-possible-to-git-diff-equivalent-with-go-git) to use  [(*object.Commit).Patch](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object#Commit.Patch), but is between commits, not branches.

Comment: I find it is usually much easier to invoke `git` with `exec.Command()` and parse what you need from the output of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Using `go-git`, you can get a Branch from [`func (r *Repository) Branch(name string) (*config.Branch, error)`](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/blob/8b0c2116cea2bbcc8d0075e762b887200a1898e1/repository.go#L528)

Or get a ref:

```
ref := plumbing.NewHashReference("refs/heads/my-branch", headRef.Hash())
```

Get a Commit from that ref, one for each branch.
That way, you can call `Patch()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
func CompareMainNHead() {
    repo, err := git.PlainOpen("./")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ref, err := repo.Head()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    refMain, err := repo.Reference("refs/heads/main", false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    commCur, err := repo.CommitObject(ref.Hash())
    treeCur, err := commCur.Tree()

    commMain, err := repo.CommitObject(refMain.Hash())
    treeMain, err := commMain.Tree()

    changes, err := object.DiffTree(treeCur, treeMain)
    fmt.Println(changes)
    diff, _ := commCur.MergeBase(commMain)
    fmt.Println("diff: ", diff)
}
```